# Why does SQL SELECT via connection.Query returns an IENumerable and SQL SELECT via MSSMS returns an integer?

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Background information**

I have a SQL Server table of events called `Events` which include 2 columns, `id` that contains a unique number per event, and `dt` which holds the date & time at which the event occurred.

I've created a list by reading table `Events` and adding new events via an API.

I update the database by going through all events and adding them if the unique id is not already in the database. The loop time is longer than is allowed and therefore, I would like to loop while the highest id in the new list is higher than the highest id in the database.

**Desired result in SSMS**

To get the latest event via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I successfully queried one of the following:

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM Events

SELECT TOP (1) [id] 
FROM Events
```

In my Console App I added the commented out lines to replace the for-loop that iterates the entire dataset:

But when I try this way, I do not get an integer but an `IEnumerable` (please ignore the cam_obj_type and Dt-Utc as I have excluded these from the example to keep it simple).

[image]

My question is: why doesn't the SQL query in my C# console app return the same result as the query in SSMS when using a `SELECT` statement, but does when using an `INSERT INTO` statement?

The class `Actions` is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AtriumConsoleApp
{

}
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: SSMS will return more than one row of data if you use `select top (2) Id`. `Query` is designed to return 0-many rows of data. You want to use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to return one and only one value. Besides that, your 2 queries are fundamentally different.

Comment: @Larnu , I updated the question; is it still open to SQL injection?

Comment: Why don't you just use an `IDENTITY` column to maintain a unique number, rather than re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: *Yes*, you are still *injecting* the values, not **parametrising** them.

Comment: I have just removed most of the code. I'll have to look into this. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Dapper method `Query<T>` which, by definition, returns a collection of `T` objects mapped from your query. If you have a query that just returns a single integer,  use the `QuerySingle<int>` method:

```
var latestID = connection.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Events");
```

Or you can also just use the core `ExecuteScalar` method:

```
using (command = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Events", conn)) 
{
    var latestID = command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using Dapper library?
If so, `Query<T>` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.
You can add a `.FirstOrDefault()` after the final parenthesis like this:

```
var yourResult = connection.Query<Actions>("..").FirstOrDefault();
```

Still, the result is a `IEnumerable` of `Actions`, not an integer.
Use `.ExecuteScalar` method as pointed above, which returns an object (the first columnf of the first row).